# Why does SWR change with coax length for not matched transmission line and load?

Tags: ham-radio

I thought that even for not perfectly matched transmission line and the attached load, the SWR value will be constant and will not depend on transmission line length assuming the line is lossless.

Measurement results I am getting are not supporting this however.

Measurements were done with NanoVNA using HF-155 cable and UC1 connectors/barrels. Used cable length was short enough so cable losses can be neglected. Results were possible to repeat and are presented in table below.

My assumption starting those measurements was that SWR will be constant regardless the length of transmission line the load is attached to (i.e. SWR measured for line lengths: 2*lambda and 2*lambda+lambda/4 will be the same for given load z0 so for all raw's in attached table the column "Difference" will be equal zero).

Could you please help me to interpret those results.

[image]

Test setup:

[image]

Comment: What does the Z0 column in your table represent? Is it the Z0 (characteristic impedance) of the transmission line used (so you used 4 different line geometries)? Or is it a setting in the VNA that you changed?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking for clarification. Z0 is the load I am attaching to coax (i.e. resistor value). Zl is the line impedance which is 50 ohm for all cases.

Comment: VNA settings in case off all measurements were unchanged.

Comment: I suspect your connectors/barrels. What does "UC1" mean? I've never heard of such a connector.

Comment: UC1 is UHF connector (comparable to N type in terms of quality). Very difficult to imagine connectors are causing problems - they are all good quality.

Comment: reference to connectors used to build the test setup: https://www.ssb.de/en/coax/coaxial-connectors/ecoflex-5/uhf

Comment: UHF connector is not comparable to N. It was designed for HF frequencies, not what we now call UHF.

Comment: Thanks John, let me do some more measurements to see if connections are an issue. In Europe we widely use both N and UHF connectors on 2m and 70cm bands.

Answer (score 1):

> My assumption starting those measurements was that SWR will be constant regardless the level of impedance match between load and transmission line.

SWR is a measure of the mismatch between the load and line. It 100% does depend on that mismatch or it would not be useful for measuring the mismatch.

> voltage values along the transmission line measured with hf probe ..., but again SWR would remain constant along the line length.

The SWR is the ratio standing wave voltage at two different points on the line (the points with maximum and minimum voltage). If you're just measuring the voltage amplitude, it doesn't make sense to talk about the SWR at a particular point on the line --- what you're measuring is the SWR of the load mismatch, by measuring multiple points on the line.

When the VNA measures SWR what it's telling you is if you connected an ideal line to the DUT at this port, what would be the SWR on that ideal line. It does that using measurements of both the amplitude and phase of the reflection produced at the port.

Your oscilloscope and probe method is only obtaining standing wave voltage values at each point, not standing wave ratios (SWRs).

Comment: I have now edited original question so it is hopefully more clear/correct.